# PHP Funciona Local (XAMPP - PHP 5.5.33) mas não funciona no Servidor (PHP 5.5.31)

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain

Estou fazendo uma API, e localmente está perfeita. O problema é quando testo ela no servidor.

Criei ela em um subdomínio, exemplo: http://api.dominio.com
E estou testando em outro subdomínio: http://teste.api.dominio.com

Localmente os endereços estão assim:

API:   http://localhost/api/public_apiv1
Teste: http://localhost/api/public_apiteste

Obs.: A estrutura de pastas está igual no servidor. Quando eu faço uma requisição inválida localmente a API me retorna uma estrutura assim:

```
{
   "error": 401,
   "message": "Permissão negada."
}
```

Porém quando testo no servidor o AJAX não retorna nada, apenas é exibido o seguinte erro no console:

[image: Erro no console]

Antes eu estava redirecionando para o *Controller* e *Action* do erro:

```
self::$controller->request->redirect(Route::href('error/unauthorized'));
```

Então pensei que redirecionamentos não funcionava com requisições AJAX, então mudei a estrutura para imprimir o resultado do *Controller* e *Action*:

```
exit(self::$controller->controller('Error', 'unauthorized'));
```

Porém continuou da mesma forma.

Já coloquei pro servidor imprimir os erros:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

E pra aceitar requisições CORS:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Porém nada é retornado do servidor.

#### UPDATE

A minha aplicação roda o seguinte código:

```
public static function validateAccess() {

   if (!self::validateApplication()) {
      exit('Está entrando aqui');
      self::$controller->request->redirect(Route::href('error/unauthorized'));
   }

}
```

O `exit` acima é exibido, se eu remove-lo e coloca-lo no Controller do redirecionamento, não é exibido mais:

```
class ErrorController extends Controller {
   public function unauthorized(){
      exit('unauthorized');
      return self::returnError('Unauthorized');
   }
}
```

O método `redirect` possui o seguinte código:

```
public function redirect($params = NULL){

   if (empty($params))
      return $this->header('Location: ' . Route::href());

   if (is_string($params))
      return $this->header('Location: ' . $params);

   if (is_array($params)){

      $controller = empty($params['controller']) ? 'main' : $params['controller'];
      $action = empty($params['action']) ? 'index' : $params['action'];

      return $this->header('Location: ' . Route::href("{$controller}/{$action}"));
   } else 
      return $this->header('Location: ' . Route::href());

   exit;
}

public function header($content) {
   header($content);
}
```

Comment: @rray segundo a imagem anexada o problema é sim com cors: `Motivo: a pré-conexão CORS falhou`

Comment: @rray é ai que está o problema, não vem nenhum erro. Sobre o _cors_ eu já adicionei o cabeçalho `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: Era bem isso que estava suspeitando, menos uma hipotese.

Comment: Por acaso o seu servidor é SoftLayer?

Comment: Não, é YCorn...

Comment: Há um tempo atrás, em uma simples aplicação, eu recebi um erro parecido com o teu. Não sei se aplica ao teu caso, mas o problema foi algumas diretrizes de segurança aplicados no firewall do servidor, não saberei te dizer exatamente o que foi.

Comment: O servidor não está rejeitando as requisições, mas está acontecendo o seguinte, quando eu tento redirecionar está abortando a requisição.

Comment: @rray atualizei a pergunta com alguns trechos de código...

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade atualizei a pergunta com alguns trechos de código...

Comment: Fiz vários testes e o código está executando até o momento do redirecionamento, mas nada é executado após isso. Requisições AJAX não são redirecionadas?

Comment: Aonde exatamente adicionou `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`? Quando ocorre o redirecionamento a página seguinte também precisará de CORS. Outra coisa, esta usando `ob_start` em algum lugar?

Comment: Guilherme, estou utilizando o Allow-Origin logo no início dos _script_, e como é um MVC, todas as requisições possui o Allow-Origin. Estou utilizando `ob_start`. apenas no carregamento da `view`. Conversei com um professor da faculdade e ele comentou que isso pode ser uma configuração padrão dos browsers, onde uma requisição _cross-domain_ não pode ser redirecionada por motivos de segurança.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após vários testes constatei que redirecionamento não funciona com requisições Ajax, provavelmente por algum motivo de segurança, quando o *browser* recebe o código `301` de redirecionamento ele já interrompe a requisição.

A solução encontrada foi encerrar a execução do *script* com o *Controller* para o qual iria redirecionar:

```
exit(self::$controller->controller('Error', 'unauthorized'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Já faz tempo seu post, mas fica para os que entrarem futuramente. Por padrão os navegadores bloqueia requisições cross domain, e é o que aconteceu com você.

Você requisitou em api.domain sendo que estava em teste.api.domain.

Uma alternativa para permitir requisições ajax cross domain é usar jsonp ao invés de json. o jsonp é muito semelhante com json com a diferença que é encapsulado em uma função e quando chega ao browser é executado para obter os dados. Este tipo de dados os browsers permitem fazer cross domain.

Geralmente quando se vai construir uma api que retorne jsonp é conveniente permitir que o client envie no corpo da requisição como parâmetro o nome padding
exemplo:

http://api.domain/users/3?jsonp=foo

o retorno será algo como:

foo({"Name": "Otto", "Id" : 3, "Age": 30});

Desta maneira o client pode determinar o que precisa para o correto parse.